# Where i can paste Piwik JS code in magento

Tags: javascript, magento, matomo

I need to integrate piwik for my site. where i can paste my piwik java-script to my magento.

Work-Out :: Copy and paste to SYSTEM->CONFIGURATION->GENERAL->DESIGN->Miscellaneous Scripts-> here

But its not working

Comment: This really should be asked on the [Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) site.